# Sorting Tasks by id from multi Tags

Tags: php, laravel, loops, for-loop, foreach

I need to sort my tasks by id and it is working fine when all tasks are from 1 tag but when there is more than one tag I get a result like the one under My Controller

My Controller :

```
$Task = Enrollee::
->with(['path.pathtags' => function ($q) use ($TagArray)
{
  $q->with(['Tasks' => function ($q) use ($TagArray)
  {
    $q->has('tasktags', '=', 2)
      ->orderBy('id', 'asc')
      ->whereDoesntHave(
        'tasktags',
        function ($query) use ($TagArray) {
          $query->whereNotIn('name', $TagArray);
        }
      )
      ->with('tasktags')->orderBy('id', 'asc');
   }]
   )->orderBy('id', 'desc');
}])
```

So My Output is like

```
Tag : Art                    
Post id : 8                     
Post Name : Post About art..               
................. 

Tag : fun           
Post id : 9                              
Post Name : Post About fun..

...................              

Tag : Food               
Post id : 11                         
Post Name : Post About food..
```

So i need to get them correctly by id

```
11                 
9               
8
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. You want to sort `tasks` or `tags`? Also, it'd be helpful to know your tables structure (`enrolees`, `tasks` `tags`)

Comment: i want to sort Tasks

Comment: But you are starting your query from the `Enrollee` class, what is the relationship? Why not go from `Task::..`

Comment: Soi can get submitted  Tasks by users it has relation with Path then  Path has (Pathtags) then every path tag has task

Answer (score 0):

You are ordering your data multiple times. I would assume that, if you have different tags, the tasks are ordered by the **tag** id in ascending order at first. Afterwards it's ordered by the task ids in descending order. Try to add some more tasks which share the same tag to see what I mean.

```
$Task = Enrollee
->with(['path.pathtags' => function ($q) use ($TagArray)
{
  $q->with(['Tasks' => function ($q) use ($TagArray)
  {
    $q->has('tasktags', '=', 2)
      ->orderBy('id', 'asc')
      ->whereDoesntHave(
        'tasktags',
        function ($query) use ($TagArray) {
          $query->whereNotIn('name', $TagArray);
        }
      )
      ->with('tasktags')->orderBy('id', 'asc');
   }]
   )->orderBy('id', 'desc');
}])
```